# How to access over WLAN usb external hard disks connected to my ubuntu desktop from my laptop or android tablet?

Tags: wireless, networking, usb

I have lots of music stored on a USB external HD connected to my Ubuntu desktop.
I wish to play them remotely over WLAN with my laptop or my android device. I can see them on the network but access is always denied for lack of 'permission' altough I have activated all possible share options and applied all imaginable permissions.
None of the solutions I have found on ask ubuntu have worked for me - or I was unable to implement/understand them...
Thanks,
dm./.

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar using a Raspberry Pi and sharing content via MiniDLNA which is available in the standard Ubuntu repo's (sudo apt-get install minidlna).  It takes only a little configuration and then the installation of a DLNA player on your Android device.  It also works for streaming to TV's and Playstation3 (probably also XBox and other devices).

A fairly good guide for setting it up can be found here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MiniDLNA